# Post on facebook wall using custom edit text instead of default fb feed

Tags: android, facebook, android-edittext

I want to post something on my facebook wall but i do not want to use the default fb feed for posting something instead of that i want to use a custom edit text that will help me on posting some data on my facebook wall.

Is there any method to do so.

please do let me know.

Comment: are you using the facebook sdk ?

Comment: yes.
I am using the latest sdk

Comment: http://androidexample.blogspot.in/2011/11/facebook-wall-post-using-android.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose If you want to post hello with a image..


public  static void postOnWall(final Activity activity,Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null)
            {

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                if(bitmap!=null)
                {
                    parameters.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
                    parameters.putString("message", "hello");

                }



                Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", parameters,HttpMethod.POST,new Request.Callback() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "picture shared successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                task.execute();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```